# php equivalent of "if example in data" in python

Tags: php, python

i am new to php from python. in the php i want to do something like "if example in data"  in python i could do what i wanted simply by doing

```
string = "this is an example"
if "example" in string:
    return True
else:
    return False`
```

is there a simple way of doing this in php? ive looked at the foreach statement as well as the if statement in php but i could not find any examples. any simple or "clean" way of doing this would be nice. and on a second note, if there is a way to get a specific result from a print_r arrray.

Comment: i had to add the last bit on because of the quality standards. could be ignored

Answer (score 1):

To check if a value exists in a string use `strpos`:

```
if (strpos($string, 'mystring') !== false)
```

To check if a key exists in an array use `array_key_exists`:

```
if (array_key_exists('key', $array))
```